# Cant understand why multiple peers isnt working in my webrtc app

Tags: javascript, sockets, webrtc, peer

I cant understand why when a third peer connects it throws this error for the third peer. I think it maybe because the connections are getting mixed up, since when 3rd peer connects he receives two offers at once
I dont know if i should do like a queue or something. Though im not sure thats the problem. Im going to try that now, but let me know if anyone can see what im doing wrong. 
Cannot read property 'setRemoteDescription' of undefined

```
componentDidMount() {
    setUserMedia();
    this.socket.emit('createOrJoin', this.props.session);
    this.socket.on('signal', (data, remoteId) => {
        switch (data.type) {
            case 'newJoin':
            console.log('joined')
                this.createPeerRtcAndStream(remoteId, (rtc) => {
                    this.createOffer(rtc, (offer) => this.socket.emit('signal', offer));
                    this.remoteClients++;
                });
                break;
            case 'offer':
                this.remoteClients++;
                this.createPeerRtcAndStream(remoteId, (rtc) => {                
                        rtc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data), () => {
                            this.createAnswer(rtc, (answer) => this.socket.emit('signal', answer));
                        });                                 
                });
                break;
            case 'answer':          
                    this.rtcs[remoteId].setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data));
                break;
            case 'candidate':
                let hisCandidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
                    sdpMLineIndex: data.label,
                    candidate: data.candidate
                });
                if (this.rtcs[remoteId] !== undefined && this.rtcs[remoteId].remoteDescription.type) {
                    this.rtcs[remoteId].addIceCandidate(hisCandidate);
                }
                break;
            case 'clientLeft':
                this.handleLeavingClient(remoteId);
                break;
            default:
                this.socket.emit('signal', { type: 'failedConnection' });
        }
    });
}


console.log('CLIENT DESC', session);
        if(session.creatingSession===false){
            if(rooms[session.sessionKey]){
                reciever = socket.id;
                socket.join(session.sessionKey);
        rooms[session.sessionKey].clients.push(socket.id); 
                socket.in(session.sessionKey).emit('signal',{type:'newJoin'}, socket.id);
            }               
        } else {    
            if(!rooms[session.sessionKey]){
                socket.join(session.sessionKey);    
                msgs[session.sessionKey] = [];        
                rooms[session.sessionKey] = {};
                rooms[session.sessionKey].clients = [];
            }               
    rooms[session.sessionKey].name = session.room;
    rooms[session.sessionKey].clients.push(socket.id);
    console.log('CREATED SESSION');
            redClient.hset('rooms', session.sessionKey, JSON.stringify(session)) 
        }
        socket.on('signal', (data) => {
            switch (data.type){
                case 'offer':
                    console.log('initiator  recieved');
                    sender = socket.id
                    io.to(reciever).emit('signal', data, socket.id);    
                 break;
             case 'answer':
                 console.log('answer recieved');            
                 io.to(sender).emit('signal', data, socket.id); 
                 break;
             case 'candidate':
                 console.log('Recieved candidate'); 
                 sender = socket.id;     
                 if(socket.io==reciever){
                    io.to(sender).emit('signal', data, socket.id);  
                 } else {
                    io.to(reciever).emit('signal', data, socket.id);    
                 }               
                 break;
             case 'failedConnection':
                 console.log('FAILED CONNECTION')
             default :
                 console.log('NO CASE EXECUTED')    
            } 

     });
```